# how to create a gradient select color

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a gradient select color([W3Schools Select Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_text_selection.asp)) for my website using CSS.
I think it would look something like this but I don't know.

```
    <!doctype html>
<p>Some Text</p>
<style>
:-moz-selection {
background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
}
::selection {
background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
}
</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't contain a question, and thus cannot be answered. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What is it that you think is not working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is still not possible today:

> If you try to style ::selection with a property that’s not on the list, then that property will be ignored. It may be tricky seeing background in that list because the property will only render a color when used on ::selection and **it won’t render a background image or gradient.**

For more info, check [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/)